# Javascript to update input is overwritten by placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple input box with a placeholder value. There is a simple function that updates its value

```
socket.on('barcode', function (data) {
    console.log('data received')
    console.log(data);
    var barcodeObj = document.getElementById("barcode")
    barcodeObj.value = data;
})
```

I set a BP on this and the code actually inserts the barcode correctly just fine, however after checking that the function sets it correctly i continue running the app and then its quickly overwritten by the placeholder again.

This is running ReactJS and there is an onChange event, but, I would expect that to fire off correctly just fine.

the input is defined like this

```
    <input
      type="text"
      id="barcode"
      placeholder="barcode.."
      value={this.state.barcode}
      onChange={this.handleBarcodeChange}
    />
```

And the handler is setup like so

```
handleBarcodeChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({barcode: e.target.value});
  }
```

which, isnt doing anything crazy.

what am i missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to get it working by injecting the  following code in to my DeviceForm react class.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
var that = this;
this.socket = io();     
this.socket.on('barcode', function (data) {
      console.log('data received')
      console.log(data);
      that.setState({barcode: data});
  });
```

This is from this code http://code.runnable.com/VOIYIALkqgAnHDmj/node-js-socket-io-and-react-js

Comment: Are you sure `handleBarcodeChange` called when you do `barcodeObj.value = data;`? You should call it explicitly, in `'barcode'` subscription

Comment: Is the react component getting re-rendered? That would wipe values that are only set once for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might just want to do something like this:

```
socket.on('barcode', function (data) {
    console.log('data received')
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({barcode: data});
}).bind(this)
```

`setState` should automatically update the DOM for you, meaning that `this.state.barcode` in your input will be automatically updated. Calling `barcodeObj.value = data;` will simultaneously trigger `onChange`, which might be causing your issue.

Comment: So, in order to do that, it looks like this code would need to be inside a react class. Is this something I'd put in the getInitialState or in the render?

Comment: I was able to get it working inside of the componentDidMount after looking at this code: http://code.runnable.com/VOIYIALkqgAnHDmj/node-js-socket-io-and-react-js